# Filter table based on data from json object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to use `JSON`type as an input parameter for stored procedure to do some filtering on the return data.

I have the following `TableA`:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
   Id INT NULL,
   Value1 VARCHAR(25) NULL,
   Value2 VARCHAR(25) NULL
);

INSERT INTO TableA (Id, Value1, Value2) values (1, 'test1', 'new1')
INSERT INTO TableA (Id, Value1, Value2) values (1, 'test1', 'new2')
INSERT INTO TableA (Id, Value1, Value2) values (null, null, 'test3')
INSERT INTO TableA (Id, Value1, Value2) values (2, 'myvalue1', 'newvalue')
```

The `JSON` parameter is dynamic - representing one or more column name and value from the above table.

```
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Filter=N'{
  "Id": 2, 
  "Value1": "myvalue1",
  "Value2": "newvalue"
}'
```

And I extract the data from the `json` and `inner join` it with the `TableA` to get the output I need:

```
...
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@Filter)
   WITH(Id INT, 
        Value1 VARCHAR(25),
        Value2 VARCHAR(25))
)
SELECT a.* FROM cte ct
INNER JOIN TableA a
  ON ct.Id = a.Id
INNER JOIN TableA b
  ON ct.Value1 = b.Value1
INNER JOIN TableA c
  ON ct.Value2 = c.Value2
```

In this particular example, I get the desired output, since I'm specifying all the columns. However, the whole reason behind using `JSON` as parameter is to be able to dynamically pass different columns (the actual table has much more columns).

If I would to pass the following filters, I will no longer get the desired output because of `inner join`.

```
SET @Filter=N'{
  "Id": 2, 
}'
...
SET @Filter=N'{
  "Id": 2, 
  "Value1": "test1"
}'
...
SET @Filter=N'{
  "Value1": "test1, 
  "Value1": "new2"
}'
...etc
```

1. Is there a way to dynamically select all the objects from json that has values and skip the nulls? Or any other suggestion on how I can resolve this issue?
2. Is there a way to check if the json has any objects in it? Based on the documentation, there's only one function `ISJSON` that validates to make sure it's in the proper format. However, if I pass: `SET @Filter=N'{}'` it's a valid json object, but it's empty.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cefc4/3)

Comment: Btw: This is a very good question! Consumable DDL and Data, own attempt, clear explanation - I'd wish we had more of this :-) +1 from my side!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TableA a
WHERE (a.Id IS NULL AND JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.Id') IS NULL OR a.Id = ISNULL(CAST(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.Id') AS INT),a.Id))
  AND (a.Value1 IS NULL AND JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.Value1') IS NULL OR a.Value1 = ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.Value1'),a.Value1))
  AND (a.Value2 IS NULL AND JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.Value2') IS NULL OR a.Value2 = ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(@Filter,N'$.Value2'),a.Value2));
```

The trick is, to replace a `NULL` with the actual column's value...

Comment: thank you for your answer. It's almost working in call cases with exception of one. If you look at the third record where `Value2="test3"` and `Id=null and Value=null`, this case will fail and not return the record. The filter I'm using is `SET @Filter=N'{"Value2: "test3"}'`.

Comment: beautiful! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not really a satisfying answer, but the approach I've used in such situations is to combine each optional field with:

```
where (value1 is null or field1 = value1)
```

This removes the ability to explicitly select `field1 is null` using the filter, and you will need to blow up your `select` statement by two expressions per parameter:

```
--SELECT * FROM TableA

DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Filter=N'{
  "Id": 1, 
  "Value1": "test1",
  "Value2": "new2"
}'
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@Filter)
  WITH(Id INT, 
       Value1 VARCHAR(25),
       Value2 VARCHAR(25))
)
SELECT a.* FROM cte filter
INNER JOIN TableA a
  ON     filter.Id = a.Id
     and (filter.Value1 is null or filter.Value1 = a.Value1)
     and (filter.Value2 is null or filter.Value2 = a.Value2)
```

#### Query Result

```
Id  Value1  Value2
1   test1   new2
```

#### Filtering with values not set

If you have a missing value in your JSON, this will not be used as a filter criterion:

```
--SELECT * FROM TableA

DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Filter=N'{
  "Id": 1, 
  "Value2": "new2"
}'
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@Filter)
  WITH(Id INT, 
       Value1 VARCHAR(25),
       Value2 VARCHAR(25))
)
SELECT a.* FROM cte filter
INNER JOIN TableA a
  ON     filter.Id = a.Id
     and (filter.Value1 is null or filter.Value1 = a.Value1)
     and (filter.Value2 is null or filter.Value2 = a.Value2)
```

#### SQL Output

```
Id  Value1  Value2
1   test1   new2
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.  I have tested your code and there're few failed test cases. In the last example you provided with the filter you're using, it should not return row 1 since we have an `AND` in the `where` clause. If I wrap everything after `AND` inside `( ...is null OR f.Value1= a.Value1..)` it fixes this issue, but the other test cases fail. Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Corrected - I was missing parentheses - every OR clause needs to be wrapped and I also pasted the wrong results. SQLFiddle is down so I can't re-check my query currently, sorry.

Comment: like I mentioned in my comment, I have tried that and it fixes the issue of the filter you used in your example. However, other test cases break. `SET @Filter=N'{"Value2": "new2"}'` or `SET @Filter=N'{"Value2": "new2", "Value1": "test1"}'` are no longer returning any data.

Comment: @Corion, the problem seems to be, that a `NULL` is taken as a meaningful value and not just something *missing*... In my answer I use a construct like `(a is null and b is null or a=isnull(b,a))`.